# OpenGL GLut compiling issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl

hi im doing an openGL project but after downloading and installing the glut library files it still wont compile and i get 12 error C3861:  identifier not found, any help would be great

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

void init(void);
void display(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char, int, int);
void resize(int, int);

int is_depth;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(40, 40);
    glutCreateWindow("3D World");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;

}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    is_depth = 1;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void display(void)
{
    if (is_depth)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    else
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0, -100.0);
        glColor3f(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f);
        glVertex3f(-100.0, 0.0, 100.0);
        glColor3f(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f);
        glVertex3f(100.0, 0.0, 100.0);
        glColor3f(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
            glVertex3f(100.0, 0.0, -100.0);     
    glEnd();

}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case 'a':
        glTranslatef(5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;

    case 'd':
        glTranslatef(-5.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;

    case 's':
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
        break;

    case 'w':
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 5.0);
        break;

    }

    display();

}

void resize(int width, int height)
{
    if(height == 0) height = 1;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0, width / height, 1.0, 400.0);

    glTranslatef(0.0, -5.0, -150.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

and my errors are

```
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(17) : error C3861: 'glutInit': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(18) : error C2065: 'GLUT_DOUBLE' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(18) : error C2065: 'GLUT_RGB' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(18) : error C3861: 'glutInitDisplayMode': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(19) : error C3861: 'glutInitWindowSize': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(20) : error C3861: 'glutInitWindowPosition': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(21) : error C3861: 'glutCreateWindow': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(23) : error C3861: 'glutDisplayFunc': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(24) : error C3861: 'glutKeyboardFunc': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(25) : error C3861: 'glutReshapeFunc': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(27) : error C3861: 'glutMainLoop': identifier not found
1>c:\users\riche\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opengl\opengl\opengl.cpp(97) : error C3861: 'gluPerspective': identifier not found
```

the glut32.dll file is in my system32 folder

my glut.h file is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include

and my glut.lib file is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib

UPDATE
added  and now i have these errors

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutMainLoop@0 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutReshapeFunc@4 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutKeyboardFunc@4 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutDisplayFunc@4 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutCreateWindow@4 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInitWindowPosition@8 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInitWindowSize@8 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInitDisplayMode@4 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInit@8 referenced in function _main
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glMatrixMode@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnable@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex3f@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3f@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTranslatef@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl keyboard(unsigned char,int,int)" (?keyboard@@YAXEHH@Z)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gluPerspective@32 referenced in function "void __cdecl resize(int,int)" (?resize@@YAXHH@Z)
1>openGL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl resize(int,int)" (?resize@@YAXHH@Z)
```

Comment: The whole step by step process, in case other people have the same problem is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8985903/744859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include gl.h, but since you are using [GLUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit), which is not included in OpenGL proper, you also need to `#include <glut.h>`.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to include gl.h before glut.h either, not sure if its that or glu but I remember one of them not being ok with it

Comment: You fixed the original errors, now you're not linking glut.lib

Comment: You should read up properly on the compiling and linking process.

Comment: @rich - Open the Properties for your project, go to the Linker/Input page, and add glut.lib to the list at Additional Dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

This problem resulted from wrong .lib linking.

In Project's properites, choose:
Configuration properties -> linker -> input

in the right column choose: additional dependencies,
add following libraries to the list, seperated by semi colon:
opengl32.lib ; glut32.lib ; glu32.lib ;

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Only use `#include <glut.h>`

GLUT contains all the gl.h functions anyway. just make sure that in the project settings you set all the dependancies for glut32.lib, openGL32.lib etc.

Answer (score -1):

i created a video on how to set up glfw. it was 20 minutes of pain, but finally got it to work.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpsC4kP2ME0
visual studio 2010 seems to be very sensitive to configuration, 
make sure configuration is set to "all configurations".